# Comparing row values with table array

Tags: excel-formula

I have numbers lets say (in one row or in one column)- `1011,3021,5683,9274,1002`

Now I have array named "myArray" like below:

```
1011    68542   136814
3021    112054  79216
5683    136814  1002
68542   79216   9274
144797  1002    1011
98150   9274    98150
112054  112054
```

Now I want to highlight those numbers from "myArray" which are not listed in `1011,3021,5683,9274,1002` (row or column value)

Can anyone give me the formula or macro?

I tried with conditional formatting, index match, Hlookup, Vlookup....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting

1. Create a list **A1:A4** -> example `1, 2, 3, 4`
2. Create a list **B1:B2** -> example `2, 4`
3. Create a **conditional formatting** on the fist list (A1:A4)
4. Select at `Format rules`  **Custom formula is**
5. Put in `Value or formula` box **=MATCH(A1:A4,B$1:B$2,0)**

Now the A2 and A4 (value 2 and 4) should be highlight

---

**Return value**

A number representing a position in lookup_array.

**Syntax**

=MATCH (lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])

**Arguments**

- **lookup_value** - The value to match in lookup_array
- **lookup_array** - A range of cells or an array reference
- **match_type** - [optional] How to match, specified as -1, 0, or 1. Default is 1

Comment: @Kavita yes you are right. I've changed the formula with MATCH